# Formatting a decimal value with ToString() to have commas as thousand separators where the amount of decimal places is unknown

Tags: c#, string, formatting, decimal, number-formatting

I have many decimals, each rounded differently:

```
decimal quantity = Decimal.Round(item.Quantity.Value, 2, 
    MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
decimal difference = Decimal.Round(quantity * eva, 0, 
    MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

When binding to the UI, I convert to string like this:

```
string Quantity = quantity.ToString("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string Difference = difference.ToString("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Is there a generic way to insert commas for thousand separators while keeping the original decimal rounding the same?

Comment: have you looked up how to use `string.Format` method.. tons of examples on the web as well as on `SO`

Answer (score 4):

Try using Format.

```
        double d = 1.234567;
        String output = d.ToString("#,##0.##");
```

Also,

```
double d = 123456789.1;
string format = d.ToString().
                  IndexOf(NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator) 
                  >=0 ? "#,##0.00" : "#,##0";
Console.WriteLine (d.ToString(format));
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wondering, I ended up using `String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:N}", difference)` and changed the `N` depending on how many decimal places I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "N" format specifier and supply the number of digits you want any number to retain. If you want each number to potentially have a different number of digits you wall have to determine the number to supply to the format string each time.

`quantity.ToString("N(digits)");`

Complete documentation is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#NFormatString